# mysql select twice itself again in one table

Tags: mysql

How to select in 1 query below. This query need re search that's find value to their own loop.

This is different from other sub query , using 1 table only

TAble T

```
| num| WHOSE        
|  1 | A      
|  1 | C   
|  2 | B    
|  2 | C    
|  3 | D
```

Criteria to match records (conditions):

1. The value in column *whose* is not *C*
2. The value in column *num* does not match a value for another record in condition 1.

I want to find the record the value 3 in column *num* (which has D for column *whose*).

```
select * from T where whose <> C and ( num is not one of c's)
```

1 A can not because C has 1

2 B can not because C has 2

3 D is what I want, because it doesn't have *C* in column *whose* nor share a value in column *num* with a record that does have *C* in the column *whose*.

Comment: See about JOIN.

Comment: 1. English pls. I do not understand a word of what you are saying! 2. Mysql and sql server are 2 different products. Which one do you use?

Comment: Put your data in a table. Your question is really hard to understand

Answer (score 0):

First select `num` of those records where `whose` is `C`. Then select those records where `whose` is not `C` and also where `num` is not one of the ones in subquery.

```
 Select * from T where whose <> 'C' and num not in (Select Num from T  where whose = 'C' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve the same result is with a [LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html) on the same table:

```
SELECT T.* 
FROM T 
LEFT JOIN T t2 on t2.num = T.num and t2.whose = 'C'
WHERE T.whose <> 'C' AND t2.whose IS NULL
```

Check it out on [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e100/4), where the result is:

```
|  num  | whose |
|   3   |   D   |
```

Additionally, a similar way to write the query is to use the [NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) clause in the *WHERE* conditions, like this:

```
SELECT T.* from T 
WHERE T.whose <> 'C' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T t2 WHERE
                                 t2.num = T.num AND t2.whose = 'C')
```

Check it out in [this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e100/6).

To read more about the comparison between EXISTS and LEFT JOIN see [this article](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/). In the summary at the end it has the following conclusions:

> MySQL can optimize all three methods to do a sort of NESTED LOOPS ANTI JOIN.
>   ...
>   However, these three methods generate three different plans which are executed by three different pieces of code. The code that executes **EXISTS** predicate is about **30%** less efficient than those that execute index_subquery and LEFT JOIN optimized to use Not exists method.
>
> That's why the best way to search for missing values in **MySQL** is using a *LEFT JOIN / IS NULL* or *NOT IN* rather than *NOT EXISTS*.